# Ignoring pip warning when doing `pip install -r`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-2.x

I am trying to install packages in a python 3.6.3 virtual environment.

When I do `pip install -r package-list.txt`, I see a warning:

```
Ignoring pip: markers 'python_version < "3"' don't match your environment
```

In my environment, `pip(3) -V` gives:

`pip 19.2.3 from /project/*******/compute_cananda_python3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

And `Python(3) -V` gives:

`Python 3.6.3`

Here's my `package-list.txt`:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
_libgcc_mutex==0.1==main
appdirs==1.4.3==pypi_0
asn1crypto==0.24.0==py36_0
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1==py36_1
blas==1.0==mkl
bzip2==1.0.6==h14c3975_5
ca-certificates==2019.6.16==hecc5488_0
...
```

I expect the packages in `package-list.txt` are all installed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is not a warning.** This is just an informational message saying that there was a dependency which is not necessary to install because the [environment marker](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) for that requirement is not matched by your local environment.

For example, pip won't install requests because I'm still on Python 3:

```
$ pip install "requests; python_version > '5'" 
Ignoring requests: markers 'python_version > "5"' don't match your environment
```

And it won't install django because I'm not running it on a potato:

```
$ pip install "django; sys_platform == 'potato'"
Ignoring django: markers 'sys_platform == "potato"' don't match your environment
```

You may safely ignore this message.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense to me. Would you please take a look at another question of mine? It is a related question to this one. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369759/pip-install-packages-failing-invalid-requirement-no-matching-distribution

Comment: You have a conda spec-file and should not be trying to use pip with that.  `pip install -r` is for requirements files, as defined [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

Comment: The package file was provided by another person so I had no idea it was only for conda :( Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Is there any way to turn off this warning? It's confusing the users of my package.

Comment: @gsingh2011 It's not a warning. Try replacing or upgrading your users. ;)

Comment: + point for including a reference to environment markers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip -V to see which version of python your pip belongs to, whether it is python2 or python3

Comment: `pip -V` shows that it belongs to `Python3.6` as this:`pip 19.2.3 from /project/*******/compute_cananda_python3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Answer (score -1):

If you have both `python2+pip2` and `python3+pip3` installed, you should invoke `python3-pip` through the `pip3` command.

eg.

```
pip3 install -r package-list.txt
```

> To ensure that you are using the correct python version, run the following command, and check whether the output of your computer matches the required.

Test1:

```
python3 --version
```

Expected output:

```
Python 3.7.4
```

Test2:

```
pip3 --version
```

Expected output:

```
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have checked my python and pip versions, as I stated in my question, they are `python 3.6.3` and `pip 19.2.3`. The warning still shows up when I do `pip3 install -r package-list.txt`.

Comment: @XiaohuiLiu As I've mentioned, you should NOT check the pip version at the very beginning BUT the version of the very Ending, which should say `(python 3.7)` instead of `(python 2.7)`

Comment: But I am doing all these in a `python 3.6.3` virtualenv, which is required for our project. Why does it make a difference using `3.7` or `3.6` when I have a warning say that I have python version < 3? Thanks

Comment: @XiaohuiLiu Perhaps you've taken my intention wrong. What I've suggested you to do is to determine the pip version (This version stands for the python version NOT the version of the `pip` package) which you were using, and make sure that you were using the correct `pip`

Comment: I just updated my question. I did check if my `pip` matches to `pyhon`, and here is what I have for pip: `pip 19.2.3 from /project/*******/compute_cananda_python3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`, and for Python: `Python 3.6.3`.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I've read about the accepted answer. THX